# Injury because of bad ergonomics

Tags: software-development, spain

Basically I am sure I have a back injury caused by my chair at work.
All material in my job is bad for the ergonomics.
I measure about 181 cm and I'm using a chair a chair that isn't suitable for my dimensions.
We never have a inspection in the workplace for ergonomics and all in this workplace is wrong for my body.
Should you report it outside the company to have an inspection?

PD:
It's a company with few workers but that does not take heed of the health of its workers.
All my colleagues are in the same situation.

Comment: Did you do anything to improve ergonomics? Ask for a better chair? Setup your desk-high correctly etc.? What was the reaction by your superiors?

Answer (score 7):

> Should you report it outside the company to have an inspection?

No, first try and get something done within the company. Once you go outside it jeapordises your position and chances of advancement, especially if you don't take it to management for a resolution first.

Answer (score 2):

First take it up with your manager, and if they don't respond
then take it up with HR, and if they don't respond
Then talk to HRs management, and if they don't respond
then take it as high into the company as people are willing to talk to you.

*then*, when you are absolutely sure nobody in the company gives a shirt about your back issues you can take it up with your union or a similar organisation, who will then probably go the same route as you.

*then*, go to relevant authorities.

If you have health insurance, your insurer might also want to help you out. Contact them in parallel with the first steps of my advice.